# Query in turtlesim tf tutorials

Tags: ros, transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently going through the tf [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) and have a doubt in particular in the tf [listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29).
In the code

```
while(n.ok())
  {
    tf::StampedTransform tf;
    try{
      listen.lookupTransform("/turtle2","/turtle1",ros::Time(0),tf);
        }
```

What does turtle1 to turtle2 frame  transformation mean? The turtle1 frame is already transformed to the world frame in the tf [broadcaster](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246699/query-in-turtlesim-tf-tutorials./) by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `tf::Listener` builds up a cache of the published transforms for all the `tf::Broadcaster`s. The `lookupTransform` method then traverses the cache at a specific time between two specific coordinate frames requested.

It is required that there is a chain of links with defined transforms between turtle1 and turtle2 to complete the `lookupTransform` call. In this example they connect through the world frame. `lookupTransform` works for any two connected links.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2016-10-29**:
So basically, when there is a lookupTransform between turtle1 and turtle2 it is traversing from turtle1->world and then world->turtle2 or vice-versa?

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2016-10-29**:
Also, when we are using the set `setOrigin` using the `tf::Transform` object, what exactly does it set origin or translations with respect to(frame). For example in the tutorials, we've set translations and rotations of turtle's pose. But these co-ordinates are with respect to what?